# Disable root login on Linux?

Tags: linux, user-accounts, root, user

I setup a Linux server. I would like to maximize security on the server to reduce any security risks. I would like to disable login for the root account, and just add the regular user to the sudo/wheel group. How can I do that (disable login for root)?

Comment: Which distro? Ubuntu is already setup like that.

Comment: CentOS. I basically want to have it setup similar to Ubuntu where root login is disabled.

Comment: From `passwd(5)` on its `-l` switch: `To disable the account, administrators should use usermod --expiredate 1 (this set the account's expire date to Jan 2, 1970).`

Comment: Is there a way to do it immediately? I am going to check that man page.